# What is difference between sizeof(int)*10 and sizeof(40)

Tags: c

A

```
int *numptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

B

```
int *numptr = malloc(sizeof(40));
```

it's on the 32bit

i can't understand what is difference.
there is no information in the book i have.

is A and B 100% same thing?

Comment: Have you considered printing the value of the two expressions? And did you mean to use `malloc(sizeof(40))` instead of just `malloc(40)`?

Comment: No it's not. `sizeof(int)*10` will be e.g. **40** if `int` occupies 4 bytes. `sizeof(40)` is the size of the `40` constant itself, which is probably **4** assuming it is an `int`.

Comment: You need to learn what the `sizeof()` operator does. It isn't what you think.

Comment: The edit invalidates the existing answers, so I had to roll it back. You may need to post a new question if you want to make that significant of a change, because that's effectively a completely different question.

Comment: my mistake. sorry guys. fisrt time in here.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine  so do i have to delete this post? i have no idea now.

Comment: No, you shouldn't delete this post because it already has well-received answers.

Comment: 정상화, Try `printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(int)*10, sizeof(40));`.

Answer (score 6):

You're allocating a different amount of space in each case.

For case A, you have first have `sizeof(int)`.  Presumably, an `int` is 4 bytes on your system, so this expression evaluates to 4.  So `malloc(sizeof(int)*10)` is allocating space for 4 * 10 = 40 bytes.

For case B, you have `sizeof(40)`.  This is giving you the size of the constant `40` whose type is `int`, so `sizeof(40)` is 4.  This then means that `malloc(sizeof(40))` is allocating space for 4 bytes.

Comment: malloc(sizeof(40) -> malloc(40). my mistake. sorry.

Comment: so this is my question. what diffrence malloc(sizeof(int) * 10) and malloc(40).

Comment: @정상화 That should be a new question, because that invalidates the existing (voted) answers.

Comment: *upvoted rather, autocorrect got me

Answer (score 3):

An `int` isn’t guaranteed to be 4 bytes wide.  It’s only guaranteed to represent values in the range `[-32767..32767]`, so it’s only guaranteed to be 16 bits (2 bytes) wide.

Yes, it’s 4 bytes on most modern desktop platforms, but it doesn’t have to be.

Besides, `10 * sizeof (int)` more clearly conveys that you’re allocating space for 10 `int` objects.

Answer (score 1):

40 is an integer, so `sizeof(40)` should return the same thing as `sizeof(int)`. Thus, `sizeof(int) * 10` is the size of 10 integers, but `sizeof(40)` is the size of a single integer.